# Proof about prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Show that if $n$ is composite then there exists a prime $p \leq n^\frac{1}{2}$ such that $p\mid n$.

I would like to use contradiction to prove this claim but I'm not sure about how I should contradict this statement.

Comment: What if all $p$ prime divisors of $n$ satisfy $p>n^\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Your question has been asked before.  See, for instance, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431930/prove-that-if-a-number-n-1-is-not-prime-then-it-has-a-prime-factor-le-sq

Answer (score -1):

Assume no prime $p<\sqrt n$ divides $n$, then there must be a prime $p$ such that $\sqrt n< p\le n$ and $p|n$ Let $m=n/p$. Because $p>\sqrt n$, $m\le\sqrt n$.  But then there is a prime $q$ such that $q|m$ and $q\le \sqrt n$.